# Integrating android-misc-widget 'Panel' into Android project

Tags: android, classcastexception, sliding, drawer

I'm running into a `ClassCastException` when trying to integrate the Panel widget from [android-misc-widgets](http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/).

I have copied the org.miscwidgets.widget and org.miscwidgets.interpolator packages into my project and am having trouble viewing the Panel show up in the graphical layout. The xml looks like this -

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:panel="org.miscwidgets.widget"..

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="37dip"
    android:paddingRight="37dip"
>
    <org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/topPanel" 
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        panel:handle="@+id/panelHandle"
        panel:content="@+id/panelContent"
        panel:position="top"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"

    >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/panelHandle" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="33dip" 
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelContent" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="60dip" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="top check box"
                android:background="#688"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bounce\nInterpolator"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#323299"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel>
    </FrameLayout>...
```

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:77)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:315)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:314)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:283)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1506)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1312)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1043)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:870)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:365)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2743)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1429)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1398)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1383)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3629)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3284)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Just trying to implement a top-down sliding drawer in android.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how did you copy the packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in the opening `LinearLayout` tag -

`xmlns:panel="org.miscwidgets.widget"`

should be

`xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/name.of.the.package.that.contains.java.file.that.uses.this.layout.file"`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: i am also facing similar problem, pls help me solve it.. provide a brief explanation about how did u solve this problem.

Comment: and pls tell what do u mean to by this? ** have copied the org.miscwidgets.widget and org.miscwidgets.interpolator packages into my project and am having trouble viewing the Panel show up in the graphical layout.** how did u copy those packages?